# How to set the pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically property from PhoneGap?

Tags: ios, cordova

I need to set the `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` property of `CLLocationManager` from PhoneGap. How can I do it?

The reason is that otherwise the location updates via `watchPosition` in JavaScript can stop coming if the user remains stationary, the fix is lost etc., and there doesn't seem to be a way to restart position tracking from JavaScript.

(The same question was asked before but doesn't have an answer:
[location update auto pause iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19887571/location-update-auto-pause-ios#comment30583954_19887571))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the code of the plugin directly:

- Open your Xcode project.
- Search for "CDVLocation.m" which is the class responsible of track the user location.
- In the `initWithWebView` method add this line:

  ```
  self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
  ```

It should work now.